# NPE in ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler when registering Resource Processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I've created a custom repository and I want it to be registered with Spring Data Rest repository following Spring-restbucks example.

```
@RestController
public class BuildingController implements ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {
    public static final String PAGES_REL = "pages";
    @Autowired(required=true)
    public BuildingController(BuildingRepository repository) {
        Assert.notNull(repository);
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    private final BuildingRepository repository;
```

When I deploy this with rest of the app I get NPE in ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler ctor.
During debugging I've noticed that all other Processors I have are regualr java objects and only BuildingController one is com.sun.proxy.$Proxy...
So issue is in with casting to Class on JDK Proxy object.

Here are the lines in ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler of code where NPE happens:

```
TypeInformation<?> componentType = from(processor.getClass()).getSuperTypeInformation(ResourceProcessor.class)
                .getComponentType();
Class<?> rawType = componentType.getType();
```

My question is how to avoid NPE?

One more thing to note is that I am trying to configure Spring with xml and Java due to the fact that I am running Application on WebLogic server which only supports servlet 2.5.
Here are excerpts from my config. I guess I am doing somthing wrong here:

My web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
    /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
    /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
   </param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.app, org.springframework.security"/>
```

And then I created java configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan( "com.my.app.platform" )
@EnableWebMvc

@EnableHypermediaSupport( type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL )
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration
{
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a root cause.

In servlet-contect.xml I had aop configured as well

```
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy >
   <aop:include name="loggingAspect"/>
 </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

So when I remove it , everything is fine.
I also tried to add proxy-target-class="true" to force CGLIB but then I've got stack overflow exception in same place???

Not sure how one combine AOP with SDR Processors though?
Any ideas?